# Selenium in Windows vs Linux (Add value to the Date picker)

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, datepicker

The Main thing is that I try to add a date to the date field which is very easy:

- Find Element / by using `.send_keys("01/01/1990")`

But the problem is that in Windows all working fine - and the date picker looks like this
[image]

But when I open it in a Linux box, the date picker opens like this (In the middle of the page with a shadow effect in the background) - which causes issues interacting with the input field:
[image]

**Extra:**

- Windows and Linux execution happening in the headless mode
- Both using the latest Chrome driver

**What I have tried:**

- Using JS to remove this date picker, hide and etc...
- using Actions / send_keys() and e.t.c...
- Using JS to add value to the element (can add visually BUT when click on empty space date disappeared )

**So, I have two questions:**

- Why is Windows and Linux date picker open differently
- What will be the way to add the date to the Linux version date picker (straight to the input .. NOT by using the date picker itself)

**UPDATE 1.0:**

- Looks like issue is smililar to this one: https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/4447

  - As in linux box it ix opened as MOBILE and not as Desktop version of the website.... any idea how to make it opened in Linux as Desktop website?
  - This does not work: `options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3")`